# One pack/package of bread vs. One loaf of bread

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say

> one [pack](https://www.alphabaking.com/12110/)/[package](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/package-bread-bears-following-100-whole-grain-stamp-based-stamp-information-know-grain-pro-q70401062) of bread

to mean "one loaf of bread"?

Comment: Grammatically correct, yes. But it's also grammatically correct to say "a loaf of milk" and "a pack of artwork", even though they make no sense. What question are you really asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. the meanings are different.  A "pack of bread" is not a common phrase, and would be used for the unusual situation in which the bread was not being sold in single loaf form.  For example pita bread may be sold in a pack. Pita bread isn't in loaf form. In these cases you would almost certainly use a more specific word than bread:  "a pack of naan", "a pack of wraps", or "a pack of baps".

Occasionally you may get packs that contain multiple loaves (your first link). Or you may want to refer to the packaging and not the bread (your second).

If you mean a package that contains one loaf then you should use "loaf of bread".

That said, the *grammar* is correct.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your explanations!

Answer (score 1):

A sliced loaf of bread is normally sold in a single package. However, because the word "loaf" is so well used and understood, people who hear (or read) the  expression "package of bread" will wonder why the word "loaf" was not used. They will most likely understand the expression to mean the package contains part of a loaf, or slices from several different loaves, or several loaves in a single package.

That said, the *grammar* is correct.